# through radio buttons i want to generate data from oracle database using ajax

Tags: sql, ajax, oracle, jsp

i have date picker text box in Jsp i want to retrieve date based on select date by clicking calender..when generate button is click it should generate data from table.i have search  a lot all codes for sys date only..i am working on generating sales report,purchase report and inventory report for supermarket...

Comment: Try to improve your message, it is hardly understandable.

Comment: add the code what you tried so far, and where you facing problem highlight it.

Comment: you can get some idea from [here](https://github.com/abhishek333/ServletAjaxDatePickerPostJson)